# Service Stack how to implement custom validation without registration

Tags: authentication, jwt, servicestack

I am learning ServiceStacks and validations. I am still pretty new to this. I am interested in validating without registering a user. For example, I would like to validate all users that begin with the specific letters. Is this possible? I have been able to implement JWT authentication with the built in templates ServiceStacks uses but I am having trouble making custom validations that do not require an email.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly where you want the validation to occur, i.e. which API?

Comment: Hello @mythz, As practice I am using the ASP.NET Identity Auth template. The idea would be to authenticate without registration directly on the loginpage and only requireauth if lets say the user entered "O" in the UserName login. Assuming the only thing I want is the UserName for authentication.

Comment: You'd need to create a [Custom Auth Provider](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#custom-authentication-and-authorization) to utilize a different Auth strategy.